# Como puedo eliminar cookies con una condicion

Tags: php, php7, cookies, setcookie

estoy desarrollando un login que pueda recordar los datos, e implemete un checkbox para poder hacerlo mediante cookies. pero el problema es que se elimina aunque que la condicion se haya cumplido. aqui le dejo mi codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
if (isset($_POST['recordar'])){
    

  $NoAsociado = $_POST['NoAsociado'];
  setcookie('NoAsociado',$NoAsociado);

  $password = $_POST['password'];
  setcookie('password',$password);

  $recordar = $_POST['recordar'];
  setcookie('recordar',$recordar);

 include dirname(__FILE__).'../../validacion/validacion.php';

}else{
  setcookie("NoAsociado", "", time() - 3600);
  setcookie("password"  , "", time() - 3600);
  setcookie("recordar"  , "", time() - 3600);

  include dirname(__FILE__).'../../validacion/validacion.php';
}
```

Comment: Estás creando la cookie con un tiempo menor al actual. Debes sumar en lugar de restar los 3600

Answer (score 1):

La función [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php) recibe tres parámetros "**obligatorios**". En realidad tiene más de tres parámetros, y la mayoría son opcionales, pero no viene al caso.

**`setcookie(nombre, valor, duración)`**

- **nombre**

  El nombre de la cookie; osea, el nombre que va a recibir la cookie en el navegador del cliente.
- **valor**

  El valor de la cookie. Aquello que luego vas a obtener mediante `$_COOKIE`.
- **duración**

  El tiempo, en segundos, que va a durar la cookie en el navegador del cliente. Este tiene que ser un [tiempo Unix](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix).

Lo que te está fallando es la definición de las cookies. Lo estás haciendo bien, pero te falta indicarle el tiempo que van a durar en el navegador. Al no indicarle el tiempo éste se establece *implícitamente* a cero y el navegador lo interpreta como una *"instrucción"* de borrado de la cookie.

Para ello tenés que indicarle la duración como el tiempo **actual** más la cantidad de **segundos** que va a durar la cookie. Para lo primero podés usar la función [time()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.time.php) el cual te devuelve la fecha y hora actual en tiempo Unix. Y para lo segundo podés usar las matemáticas.

```php
$duracion = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // 1 año
setcookie('recordar', $recordar, time() + $duracion);
```

En tu código sería así:

```php
if (isset($_POST['recordar'])){

  $duracion = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // 1 año

  $NoAsociado = $_POST['NoAsociado'];
  setcookie('NoAsociado',$NoAsociado, $duracion);

  $password = $_POST['password'];
  setcookie('password',$password, $duracion);

  $recordar = $_POST['recordar'];
  setcookie('recordar',$recordar, $duracion);

 include dirname(__FILE__).'../../validacion/validacion.php';

}
```